# Python System Call Cannot Find File, Error Running on Apache Server

Tags: android, python, django, linux, apache

I'm trying to run an `os.system()` call from my Python class to source a file I have stored in the file. I am connecting to a server from an Android application and running a method in Django to run a system call. The server is running Apache with `mod_wsgi` to deploy Django. This is the Django method:

```
def post_try(request):
    os.chdir("/usr/local/src")
    response = os.system("source sourceme")
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

The code works fine as far as syntax goes, all necessary imports are done, however I keep getting a 256 error code back instead of the expected 0. I check the error in the Apache log and this is what I get:

```
[Sun Aug 18 19:43:23 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Aug 18 19:43:24 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sun Aug 18 19:43:24 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sun Aug 18 19:43:24 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Aug 18 19:46:04 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Aug 18 19:46:05 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Sun Aug 18 19:46:05 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Sun Aug 18 19:46:05 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
sh: line 0: source: sourceme: file not found
```

I cannot figure out what is going on. I have the sourceme file clearly in the `/usr/locals/src/` folder, which I have verified many times using ls. I do not know what is happening. I used `os.getcwd()` to check that the directory is being changed correctly, but the file still cannot be found. Please let me know if there is anything that I am missing, as I am very frustrated at this problem that I can just not realize.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach currently does not make sense:
`os.system` creates a child process of the WSGI process, while the environment of the parent is passed on to the child, the environment of the child is not passed back/shared with the parent.

Also, `source` is not a binary, but a built-in function of the shell itself.
If you want to set environment variables us `os.environ` which is a dictionary of the variables.

Since you are using python, it would be much more sensible to use python program instead of some `os.system` calls. That is, create python program with the environment variables, add it to your `PYTHONPATH` and import it in your django code.

Comment: To exand a bit on Uku's answer:  os.system ('source sourceme') is looking for an executable in your path called 'source sourceme', and it's not finding it.